# Access the `access_token` property in localstorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have saved the token in localstorage: localStorage.setItem ('token', JSON.stringify (res.data)). I am trying to access the `access_token` property.

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(token['access_token']))`

It gets error: `token is undefined`;

```
 getToken = () => {  
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

    const url = '/oauth2/token';

    axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url, 
      data, 
      config
    }) 
      .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data))
          this.setState({
            token: res.data
          })

        } else {
          const error = new Error(res.error);
          throw error;
        }
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.error(err);
        alert('error'); 
      });
  }
```

Comment: Try this:
let tokenObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
let token = tokenObj['access_token'];

Comment: can you also share the code how you are trying to get the access token and at which point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You syntax needs to be corrected to as below

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))['access_token']
```

Comment: I'm trying without JSON.parse, localStorage.getItem('token')['token_type'], but I have undefined

Comment: You will have to use JSON.parse as "res.data" was stringified before saving to localstorage

Comment: Thanks.. what worked for me was JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))['access'].. I'm using django simplejwt

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var tokenData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
console.log(tokenData.access_token);
```

Example how to store object in localStorage

```
var myObj = {
    one: {
        title: 'first',
        id: 1,
        customKey : {
            first: "first",
            second: "second"
        }
    },
    two: {
        title: 'second',
        id: 2
    },
    three: {
        title: 'this is the third',
        id: 3
    }
};

localStorage.setItem('storeObj', JSON.stringify(myObj));

var getObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
```